# Custom Alert View in Slide Over for iPad in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, uiview

I seem to be having some trouble with a custom alert view class that I have created.  The alert appears in the center of the display when the application is running full screen, however, when the app is running in slide over, the alert does not appear correctly.  Any thoughts on why this is the case?  My code for my class is as below:

```
import UIKit

class AlertView: UIView {


    @IBOutlet weak var dismissButton:UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var errorLabel:UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var errorImage:UIImageView!




    func setAlertView(message:String) {

        errorLabel.textColor = .white

        self.backgroundColor = greyColor
        self.layer.borderWidth = 0
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 10

        self.transform = CGAffineTransform.init(scaleX: 1.3, y: 1.3)
        self.alpha = 0
        errorLabel.text = message
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4) {
            self.alpha = 1
            self.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
        }

    }



    @IBAction func dismissAlertView() {

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
            self.transform = CGAffineTransform.init(scaleX: 1.3, y: 1.3)
            self.alpha = 0
        }) {(succes:Bool) in
            self.removeFromSuperview()
        }

        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name(rawValue: "ErrorDismissed"), object: nil, userInfo: nil)

    }


    override init (frame : CGRect) {
        super.init(frame : frame)
    }

    convenience init () {
        self.init(frame:CGRect.zero)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }



}
```

Comment: From where you are creating a frame for AlertView?

Comment: That might be my issue.  I set the size of the view in the interface builder.  but I only set the center of the view in the view controller.  Such

self.view.addSubview(alert)
alert.setAlertView(message: errorString)
alert.center = self.view.center